# Multiple read more in same div with full content with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three read more link on the page and using jquery toggle these are working fine. But i want when, i click read more link the full content is display in another div with a close button.
Here is my code:
HTML:

```
<div class="comment more">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Vestibulum laoreet, nunc eget laoreet sagittis,
quam ligula sodales orci, congue imperdiet eros tortor ac lectus.
Duis eget nisl orci. Aliquam mattis purus non mauris
blandit id luctus felis convallis.
Integer varius egestas vestibulum.
Nullam a dolor arcu, ac tempor elit. Donec.
</div>
<div class="comment more">
Duis nisl nibh, egestas at fermentum at, viverra et purus.
Maecenas lobortis odio id sapien facilisis elementum.
Curabitur et magna justo, et gravida augue.
Sed tristique pellentesque arcu quis tempor.
</div>
<div class="comment more">
consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin blandit nunc sed sem dictum id feugiat  quam blandit.
Donec nec sem sed arcu interdum commodo ac ac diam. Donec consequat semper  rutrum.
Vestibulum et mauris elit. Vestibulum mauris lacus, ultricies.
</div>
<div class="dis">
 //the full content displayed here.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
a {
color: #0254EB
}
a:visited {
color: #0254EB
}
a.morelink {
text-decoration:none;
outline: none;
}
.morecontent span {
display: none;
}
.comment {
width: 400px;
background-color: #f0f0f0;
margin: 10px;
}
.dis{
display: none;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background-color: blue;
color: red;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var showChar = 100;
var ellipsestext = "...";
var moretext = "more";
var lesstext = "less";
$('.more').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();

    if(content.length > showChar) {

        var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
        var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);

        var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp; </span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=""  class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

        $(this).html(html);
    }

});

$(".morelink").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
        $(this).removeClass("less");
        $(this).html(moretext);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("less");
        $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
});
});
```

Link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqNMbQ

Answer (score 0):

you can change you $(.morelink).click() function to this.

```
$(".morelink").click(function(){

    if($(this).hasClass("less")) {

        $(this).removeClass("less"); 
        $(this).html(moretext);
        $('.dis').html('');
        $('.dis').hide();

    } else {
    var content = $(this).siblings('span').html();

        $(this).addClass("less");
        $(this).html(lesstext);
        $('.dis').html(content);
        $('.dis').show();

    }
   // $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    //$(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
});
```

hope this is what you want.